# When to use zone.run()?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection, ngzone

I tried to read a lot about `NgZone` in angular. I got to know that angular uses `zone.js` for change detection. I see some code used zone.run and place few actions inside of it.

What does it do actually?

Still I could not figure out the actual use of `zone.run`

```
this.zone.run(() => {
     /* my code here */
});
```

With the help of this [link](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html#demos), I understood little bit.

Comment: Why is this question related to ionic4?

Comment: now its ok.....

Comment: If you not run that method, the view will not get update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is itself provided in the blog which you have mentioned. I'll try to break it down further. In the [given example](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html#running-code-outside-angulars-zone) :

> Situation: You are creating a `progress-bar` component whose value will be updated every 10 milli seconds

#### Without `NgZone`:

Once `button` is clicked , `increaseProgress()` will be called with a function (whose value will be displayed once the progress bar is complete)

```
    <button (click)="processWithinAngularZone()">
      Process within Angular zone
    </button>
```

it calls itself every 10 milli seconds and it keeps on increasing `this.progress` counter till `100`

```
increaseProgress(doneCallback: () => void) {
  this.progress += 1;
  console.log(`Current progress: ${this.progress}%`);

  if (this.progress < 100) {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.increaseProgress(doneCallback);
    }, 10);
  } else {
    doneCallback();
  }
}
```

This will work but ***since we are using `setTimeout`, the `ChangeDetection` cycle will be triggered every `10 milliseconds` which will impact performance of application***

---

#### With `NgZone`:

With `ngZone` we are passing, `zone.run()` rather than `console.log`. This would basically act as a trigger for `ChangeDetection` once the counter is complete.

Now, to avoid the *effect of `setTimeout` (which triggers `ChangeDetection`because of monkey patching)*, we wrap the entire execution block inside `this.zone.runOutsideAngular`.  The `ChangeDetection` is only invoked when we explicitly call `zone.run()`.

```
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.increaseProgress(() => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log('Outside Done!');
      });
    });
  });
```

---

Similar use case :

1. Let's say you need to implement some logic on `scrollEvent` which might trigger a function which could result in triggering of `ChangeDetection`. To avoid this, we can use `zone.runOutsideAngular` and manually trigger the `ChangeDetection` after certain action/duration using `zone.run()`.
2. You are using some 3rd party library (which works outside of Angular `ChangeDetection`) and you need to manually trigger `CD` after some event of that 3rd party library.

Its not very frequent to use this, but yes , its can create unwanted behaviors when not known.

I hope it has helped you understand the concept better